# Optimization, multivaraible

Tags: optimization

I have a question regarding multivariable optimization. **In particular, I have a function f(x,y,z,w) and I want to maximize f in terms of x only (with other variables treated as parameters).**  Also I have one more constraint: y=g(x), that is, this constraint is an equation of only y and x.

To maximize f, all I have to do is to substitude y for y=g(x), and then I $d/dx[f(x,y=g(x),z,w)]=0$, then just solve for x.

**Here is the problem. I don't think I can solve for x.**

---

So I decide to  do the followings:

1) substitude $x=g^{-1}(y)$ to f.

2) f is now $f(g^{-1}(y),y,z,w)$

3)$d/dy[f(g^{-1}(y),y,z,w)]$=0, then solve for y.

4) after I obtain answer for y, then using the constraint, I could get x.

**Now, do you think what I do in above 4 steps optimize f in terms of x?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, I think that there are two different approaches. You want to maximize $$F(x,y,z,w)$$ subject to the the contraint $y=g(x)$, $z$ and $w$ being parameters.

The first approach (what you did) could be to write $$F(x,y(x),z,w)$$ and compute its derivative with respect to $x$ which is a single equation in $x$. This would give $$y'(x)F'_y+F'_x=0$$

The second approach will imake use of Lagrange multipliers and this would correspond to the maximization of $$\Phi(x,y,z,w)=F(x,y,z,w)+\lambda \Big(y-g(x)\Big)$$ but this will require to solve $$\Phi'_x=\Phi'_y=\Phi'_{\lambda}=0$$.

I definitely think that the first approach is the simplest.

Comment: Do u think it is correct with my 4 steps? Because I want to optimize in terms of x, but in those 4 steps, I can taking derivative with y

Comment: Honestly, I think that you are making your life more difficult than required. I added to my answer. Could you provide an example ? Cheers :)